# Which of following must be true?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $W$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ and $T: R^6->W$ be a linear transformation such that $S=\left\{Te_2  , Te_4 ,Te_6\right\}$ span $W$.
Which one of following must be TRUE?

a). $S$ is a basis of $W$.

b). $T(\mathbb{R}^6)\neq W$.

c). $\left\{Te_1 , Te_3 ,Te_5\right\}$ spans $W$.

d). $Ker(T)$ contains more than one element.

I get that obviously (b) is not true, otherwise $T$ won't be a linear transformation.

(c) won't be true because of the given condition.

Also, I get that if (a) is true then (d) won't be true.

and if (a) is false then (d) will be true.

What I did not understand is that (a) is true or false?

Also is the reasoning to cancel out option b, c true?

Comment: $S$ spans $W$, but seemingly you don't have the claim of independency of elements of $S$.

Comment: I don't see any problem with $b.$

Comment: a) does not have to be true, you can have $T = [0,1,0,2,0,3]$.

Comment: a) does not have to be true: for example, $W$ could be $0$ and $S=\{0\}$.

Comment: @BabakS. can you please prove the dependency of S?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of these possibilities (b) is false. (a) and (c) may be false. Only (d) must be true.

(b):
$W\supset T(R^6)\supset {\rm Span} S = W$

(a): $W$ could be of dimension strictly smaller than 3 (even zero).

(c): For that matter all these vectors may map to zero which may be different from $W$.

(d): $\dim \ker T \geq 6 - 3 =3$ so must be non-trivial.

Comment: Elaborate your explaination for (d) part please.

Comment: $\dim W\leq 3$ (because spanned by 3 vectors). For any linear map $T: R^6 \rightarrow W$  we have: $6 =\dim (R^6) =\dim \ker T + \dim {\rm im} T = \dim \ker T +\dim W \leq  \dim \ker T +3$

Answer (score 1):

a) is not **necessarily** true. Indeed, it could be that $Te_2=Te_4$ for example, so that $\{Te_2,Te_4,Te_6\}$ isn't linearly independent.

However, d) must be true, by the rank nullity theorem.

Also, you're arguments for b) and c) are not quite correct. b) and c) **can** be true but they **must not** be true. Try to find counterexamples, like the one I gave for a).

Comment: I am with you about $d$. It is indeed true. +

Comment: Care to explain (a) again?

Comment: A basis of $W$ is a set that spans $W$ and that is linearly independent. It is given that $S$ spans $W$, but it's not necessarily true that it is linearly independent. See my counterexample.

Comment: yes, i actually didn't get your counterexample itself. Te_w = Te_4 ??

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I meant $Te_2=Te_4$.

Comment: What transformation "T" are you taking here so that Te_2 =Te_4 ?